# Copy files in C with cmd command 'copy'

Tags: c, cmd, copy

i wan to copy a file to a local network in C. 
I search but i didn't find a version for C

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );

    if (!CreateProcess( L"C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe", L"C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe copy a.txt \\share\\4vlad\\b.txt", NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi) )
    {
        printf("Error %d",GetLastError());
    }
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

But this code doesn't working. 
Can someone say me what is wrong in this code ? 
Thanks!

Comment: What is not working? Does the program crash? Do you get an error message? Does the program work, but is the file not copied?

Comment: Program it's start, open a new cmd window, but the file was not copied.

Comment: Would't it be easier just to use [`CopyFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363851(v=vs.85).aspx) or [`CopyFileEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363852(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Comment: So @WhozGraig i  try with Copy file with command CopyFile(L"C:\\Windows\\system32\\calc.exe", L"\\share\\4vlad\\calc.exe", TRUE)), but it's not working  when i want to copy on a local network, but on hardisk is working. And i got error ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND

Comment: Two things. First I think you have your unc path incorrect. UNC paths are `\\server\sharename\folder`. Since I doubt your server is called `share`, you likely meant to say `\\4vlad\server\calc.exe`.  Second, are you sure your share was connected before you attempted the `CopyFile` ?

Comment: did you try "\\\\share\\4vlad\\calc.exe" as remote path?

Comment: Yeah, path is \\share\4vlad\, but if you don't use double\\ will you got an error, so need to use \\. What do you mean with "your share was connected before you attempted the ", our local network \\share is public in local net

Answer (score 0):

You have improper escape sequences in your destination path.   Most network shares are going to be accessed like *\\share\project\foo\data* but in your version of C `\` is an escape sequence.   To get the character `\`, you need two of the `\\` marks.

So :

`\\` becomes `\`

`\\\\` becomes `\\`

Therefore :

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );

    if (!CreateProcess( L"C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe",
        L"C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe copy a.txt \\\\share\\4vlad\\b.txt",
        NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi) )
    {
        printf("Error %d",GetLastError());
    }
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```